# How can I allow a blank value on a lookup field in a TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi

I have a column in my dbgrid that is based on a lookup field.

The problem is that the end user can't set a blank value for the field - they can only select values from the lookup table.

How can I allow the end user to delete or 'blank out' a value for the column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the appropriate TDBGrid Key event, trap for DEL.  When detected, check to see if you're in the lookup column.  If so, call Clear on corresponding dataset field.

Comment: How can I tell if I'm in the lookup column?

Comment: Read DBGrid.SelectedIndex or, even better, DBGrid.SelectedField which will give you the field object to Clear() directly.

Comment: Well, that's really close.  I'm calling something like grid.SelectedField.Clear, but it doesn't seem to work.  The field is unaffected in the grid.

Comment: Ok, here's what I came up with that works:

      with grid.DataSource.Dataset do
      begin
        Edit;
        FieldByName('fieldname').Clear;
        Post;
      end;

Probably a better way of doing it, but that works.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I was able to get you close, even if not all the way.  Not sure I've done this in a grid before, but I have with DBComboBox set to DropDownList style — same idea, but easier to get back to the appropriate field object.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a blank value in the lookup table.

Comment: I thought of that - surely there's a way to do this without adding extra data...?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The point of a lookup is to give you choices based on a list defined somewhere else.  If you start adding options that aren't on that list then you no longer have a lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code which works in Delphi XE7. The trick is to NULL the KeyField referred to by the lookup field, not the lookup field itself.

Note that it doesn't work once the dropdown box is shown e.g. when double-clicking the cell (whether dropped down or not), or if the grid's Options include dgAlwaysShowEditor. In this case, key presses are not passed to the event handler. If I get that to work as well, I'll update the code. (Any ideas???)

```
procedure TformMain.DBGridKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  LookupResultField : TField;
begin
  if Key = VK_DELETE then
    if TDBGrid(Sender).SelectedField.FieldKind = fkLookup then begin   // if this field is a lookup field

      if not (TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.State in [dsInsert, dsEdit]) then  // if the query is not already in edit mode
        TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.Edit;

      LookupResultField := TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName (TDBGrid(Sender).SelectedField.KeyFields);
      LookupResultField.Clear;            // set the field to NULL

    end;
end;
```

Comment: Everywhere (Sender) is used, I get the error E2066 Missing operator or semicolon. So i can't build this code. Delphi 10 Seattle. How is working for you??

Comment: @diedie2, just checking - do you have this as the OnKeyDown event handler for your DBGrid?

I have just tried compiling it in Delphi 10 Seattle, and I get no errors. When you double-click on the OnKeyDown event in the property inspector, does it take you to this procedure in your code, or somewhere else?

Comment: @diedie2, please send me your code - paste it into a comment here. Also tell me what is the name of your TDBGrid object?

Comment: I found my error and now it's working! many thanks! My fault was that I was using MainDBGrid(Sender) instead of TDBAdvGrid(Sender). So i used the name of my component instead of the component itself. I feel so stupid...